# SharePoint 2019 content search Query

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2019, query

I am currently attempting to only pull the Yes from the column in a list . I only want items that are set to yes in the list to be pulled the column is already in my search scheme and managed properties are turned on for the list. I am attempting to use `path:https://myurl/list AND DisplayonHomepage:1`

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on your error.

Comment: I am receiving all my site even outside of my path query. example i have 364258 results when i should have 12 results It looks like my Displayonhomepage is what is causing all the results if i jsut filter on path i get 12

Comment: do check my answer if this resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your objective is to retrieve a list of items from a specific list that match a certain Yes/No field criteria, then an appropriate filter query could resemble the following:

`path:http://server/site/yourlist AND contentclass:sts_listitem AND DisplayonHomepage:1`

Alternatively, if you have a content type specified, you can retrieve all items from any list that correspond to that content type by using the query:

`spcontenttype:mycontenttype`

Comment: I am receiving no results for the above Query

Comment: You ll need to try query with just ``path`` and ``contentclass``, see if that gives the results and then you can check the yes/no field afterwards.

Comment: I get 12 results if i filter withoutDisplayOnHomePage:1 could i have mapped my property wrong?

Comment: Check if the field name is correct there.

Comment: I recreated the column as a site columns and it started working thank you!